# JSON where query on Parse Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, parse-platform

I have an entity on parse where I have some user records. I'm fetching all the entities, writing to disk and processing them in db. This part works fine.

However I want to fetch only records for a certain user.

When I try it with my json query:

```
{"updatedAt":{"$gte":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-06-07T15:58:46.999Z"}},"userName":"xxxx"}
```

This fetches all the records in the entity ignoring my userName criteria in where query.

What am I doing wrong here? Is my JSON wrong?
Here is my NSDictionary for JSON:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'999Z'"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+2"]];

        NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                                stringWithFormat:@"{\"updatedAt\":{\"$gte\":{\"__type\":\"Date\",\"iso\":\"%@\"}},\"userName\":\"xxxx\"}",
                                [dateFormatter stringFromDate:updatedDate]];

        parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:jsonString forKey:@"where"];
```

Comment: Create an `NSDictionary` directly, there is no need for `jsonString`. Doing your own JSON formatting is just begging for bugs.

Comment: I've checked some examples but couldn't see an example with "where" clause. Can you provide me any source or sample code?

Comment: Sorry, one does not learn from examples. The proper method is to read and study the documentation, not just look at examples. Fun: No. But it is the only way to obtain a mastery.